# Is there a way to validate all fields in a form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state object that looks like this

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({
  question : "",
  topic:"",
  age:"",
  gender: "",
  consent:"",
  questionSent:false
})
```

and two functions that handles input change and checkbox.

```
let handleInputChange = event => {
 const target = event.target;
 const value = target.value;
 const name = target.name;
 setValues({
   ...values,
   [name]: value,
 });
};

let handleCheckboxChange = event => {
 const target = event.target;
 const value = target.checked;
 const name = target.name;

 setValues({
  ...values,
  [name]: value,
 });
};
```

I want to check every field for a falsy value when I click the submit button and also output the respective fields that are missing a value like this:

```
Please choose :
 
- Question
- Age
- Gender
```

Comment: https://it.reactjs.org/docs/forms.html could help?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a function like this to check for empty values

```
checkForEmptyValues = (values)=>{
return values.map((value,index)=>{
    if(value !==undefined || value !== null){
         if(value.replace(/\s+/g, " ").trim().length === 0) {
            return false
          }
         else{
            return true;
          }
    }
     if (value==="") {
         return false;
        }
     else{
         return false
        }
    }
)
```

}
and then pass your fields to check as

```
checkForEmptyValues([question,age,gender]);
```

so it will return an array with true/false like if gender is empty and other have values it will be like

```
[true,true,false]
```

with this you can easily identify empty fields and generate error messages

hope that answers your question